# PayPal IPN only works with simulator not sandbox or live

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, jigoshop

My scripts work perfectly with the ipn simulator but it will not work with a sandbox transaction. If I change the url to the live site, it will not work. The simulator prints the incoming post to a file. When using a transaction, nothing happens. How can I make this work?

edit: My wordpress plug-in is overriding paypal's ipn by setting a custom notify_url value. I tried putting the function I need to fire in the Payment complete Jigoshop action but the $_POST variable is either changed or not present. If I fill in these fields with strings, it works fine. This is what I need to fire.

```
$data = array();
$data['Name'] = $_POST['address_name'];
$data['Company'] = '';
$data['Address1'] = $_POST['address_street'];
$data['Address2'] = '';
$data['City'] = $_POST['address_city'];
$data['State'] = $_POST['address_state'];
$data['Zip'] = $_POST['address_zip'];
$data['Country'] = $_POST['address_country'];
$data['Ship_Method_MSID'] = '1STCLASS';
$data['SpecialInstr'] = $_POST['memo'];
$data['Items'] = array(array('Item_ESID' => 'EVENTBAG', 'Quantity' =>    intval($_POST['quantity'])));

$json_data = json_encode($data);
$post_data = array('AccountID' => 10019, 'SecretKey' ='jsjxb', 'Method' => 'AddShipment', 'JSON' => $json_data);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
file_put_contents('test.txt', $returndata);
```

This is what I came up with:

```
$data = array();
$data['Name'] = $paypal_args['first_name'] . " " . $paypal_args['last_name'];
$data['Company'] = '';
$data['Address1'] = $paypal_args['address1'];
$data['Address2'] = $paypal_args['address2'];
$data['City'] = $paypal_args['city'];
$data['State'] = $paypal_args['state'];
$data['Zip'] = $paypal_args['zip'];
$data['Country'] = $paypal_args['country'];
$data['Ship_Method_MSID'] = '1STCLASS';
$data['SpecialInstr'] = '';
$data['Items'] = array(array('Item_ESID' => 'EVENTBAG', 'Quantity' => intval($paypal_args['quantity_1'])));

$json_data = json_encode($data);
$post_data = array('AccountID' => 10019, 'SecretKey' => 'z1', 'Method' => 'AddShipment', 'JSON' => $json_data);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
file_put_contents('test.txt', $returndata);
```

Which came from:

```
if ($this->send_shipping=='yes') :
                    $paypal_args['no_shipping'] = 1;
                    $paypal_args['address_override'] = 1;
                    $paypal_args['first_name'] = $order->shipping_first_name;
        $paypal_args['last_name'] = $order->shipping_last_name;
        $paypal_args['address1'] = $order->shipping_address_1;
        $paypal_args['address2'] = $order->shipping_address_2;
        $paypal_args['city'] = $order->shipping_city;
        $paypal_args['state'] = $order->shipping_state;
        $paypal_args['zip'] = $order->shipping_postcode;
        $paypal_args['country'] = $order->shipping_country;
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?  Are you seeing that the IPN is being triggered but you're getting an error in your logs, or are you saying that IPN is not getting sent at all?  You can check IPN History in your PayPal account (live or sandbox) to double check this.

Comment: If the IPN simply isn't getting sent then you need to make sure it's configured in your seller account profile.

Comment: I have enabled it. Nothing shows in my history or in my logs. I read a post stating that paypal doesn't send to example.com/php/ipn.php, and that it needs to be example.com/ipn.php I will try that when I get home to day. The ipn simulator works perfectly.

Comment: It will send to whatever URL you have configured for it, but you need to make sure it's configured in the correct account.

Comment: It is configured properly in my sandbox account. My website is a jigoshop Wordpress setup. Jigoshop somehow gets ipn's sent to it even though my paypal account is set to something different. The paypal ipn history shows ipn"s being sent to jigoshop's listener but not mine.

Comment: Ok, that means your Jigoshop system is using the Notify URL parameter to override what your profile is using.  What you'll need to do is extend their IPN solution to do what you're doing in yours so that both sets of actions of occur.  You could setup a daisy chain, too, and simply POST the same IPN data to your script from the Jigoshop script.  That way both of them would run.